# what is advantage of StructLayoutAttribute in C# struct

Tags: c#, attributes

I came across the use StructLayoutAttribute but I dont know how it is helpful for use. I have a struct like

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct XYData
{

    public int x;

    public int y;

    public XYData(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Applying the attribute StructLayoutAttribute will help us?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Answer is likely no, and probably you should not be using struct either... But describing your problem where you need to use struct may lead to anohter more detailed answer.

Comment: Nothing, a struct's layout is already sequential.

Comment: I am using this struct in interop services.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh, I  don't know - an `x`/`y` pair is not a bad candidate for `struct`, as long as it is made immutable

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: On a `class` yes, but not on a `struct`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: "To reduce layout-related problems associated with the Auto value, C#, Visual Basic, and C++ compilers specify Sequential layout for value types." From your link O_o

Comment: Thanks @leppie for comments that I took liberty to convert into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in [StructLayoutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) C# already using `Sequential` for struct. So technically there is no impact of adding this attribute:

> C#, Visual Basic, and C++ compilers apply the Sequential layout value to structures by default.

You can safely add this value to your struct in C# code as it will explicitly document the intent, but it is optional.

If you are emiting the structure yourself or using IL directly you need to specify it.

Note that for classes you need to specify `Sequential` directly if you find that you need particular layout of fields in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Only if this struct is marshaled to unmanaged code

[See MSDN Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx)